# Why do Gaudiyas believe that Krishna and Gopis are eternal teenagers?

Tags: scripture, krishna, vaishnavism, gaudiya-vaishnavism

I have heard that Gaudiyas believe that Krishna is eternally 15 years old and that Lalita is eternally 14 years old.

Why do they believe this? Is this stated in scripture?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is confirmed by several gaudiya acharyas including Srila Jiva Goswami (one of the six goswami) in his tika of Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam. Srila Prabhupada discusses this in SB 10.45.3 https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/45/3/

Comment: It's better you include the discussion you are referring to in the answer, rather than just sharing a link. If you just want to share the link, then comments section below the question would be better for that content. But in answer, you need to be elaborate.

Comment: Did they believe this based on their own reasoning from scripture, or was it specially revealed to them?

Comment: @TerjijKassal Jiva Goswami is considered to be the incarnation of Vilasa Manjari, an eternal maidservant of Radharani. Lord resides in his eternal abode golok where he is eternally kishore. In Brahma samhita 5.33: advaitam acyutam anādim ananta-rūpam
ādyaṁ purāṇa-puruṣaṁ **nava-yauvanaṁ** ca
vedeṣu durlabham adurlabham ātma-bhaktau
govindam ādi-puruṣaṁ tam ahaṁ bhajāmi

Comment: @ShastraDigger add your comment to your answer please. And the key contents of the link too.